# -webkit-animation-play-state not working on iOS 8.1 (probably lower too)

Tags: ios, css-animations

I have an animation running on page load and with javascript I add a class containing the

```
-webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
```

Working fine on OSX safari and all other browsers (even PC) too but on mobile, only on iOS that the animation doesn't seem to paused when called.

Here's a fiddle on how the animation state is running and paused.

http://jsfiddle.net/uc9c5/2/

Try it on iOS, you'll see that it's totally ignored.

Comment: Can confirm. `paused` seems to be completely ignored and `running` restarts the animation. Great.

Comment: In my case, I have "pause" class on my body with :paused state on document load which is fine. It paused all animation. When I remove that "pause" class all animation starts to play but if I put back that "pause" class it doesn't effect any more. One thing I noticed that it pause the steps animation but not others.

Comment: i put my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683012/css-animation-play-state-paused-doesnt-work-in-ios/33250632#33250632

Comment: @duchuy probably should put it here too so I could accept it ;)

Comment: Did you find any solution, yet? I have the exact same question, BUT the stated workaround below is not what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workaround approach for iOS 8-9 Safari that use **-webkit-animation: none !important;** instead of **-webkit-animation-play-state:paused;**
This approach is for GWD, but can apply otherwise

1. Don't use Pause event in GWD (Google Web Designer)
2. Create normal event that calls a javascript function, set "-webkit-animation: none !important;" to the <div> (you can add/remove css class)

CSS Style

```
.no-animation {
  -webkit-animation: none !important;
}
```

Javascript

```
div.className = div.className + " no-animation";
```

3. To resume, remove CSS class

Javascript

```
div.className = div.className.replace("no-animation", '');
```

4. Please note that when remove/pause animation, it will go back to frame 0 (00:00 s), so you may need to calculate the current opacity/position for the div

http://jsfiddle.net/duchuy/pczsufL9/